# Stop regex from searching after hitting the first specific string instead of going to the last one

Tags: regex

I have a file that looks like this:

```
<target>randomnumber1
</target>
<target>randomnumber2
</target>
<target>randomnumber3
</target>
```

I need a regex that will find

```
<target>randomnumber1
</target>
```

and stop there instead of finding everything from the first `<target>` until the very last `</target>`.

I tried this regex

`<target>[^\r]*</target>`

but it fails, because there is `\r` after randomnumber1 and so on.

The basic idea would be to simply to tell regex to stop after it hits the first `</target>`.

Comment: I edited your question. Please recheck if I haven't messed up something

Comment: You are looking for [non-greedy quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) like `<target>.*?</target>`. Additionaly we need to know what program (regex engine) you use, so we can tell how to search for multilines. For notepad++ it would be [this setting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5NA4K.png)

Comment: Thanks, nixda. `target>.*?</target` does the trick in notepad++ with the . matches newline option set. Is there any way to adjust this regex to work in a custom program that does not have such option, though?

Comment: [Here is a SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression) which covers some possible solutions depending on which engine your custom program will use. I guess there is no *general* solution

Comment: Excellent! `<target>(.|\n|\r)*?</target>` does the trick. Thank you so much.

Comment: You should make this an answer. It's totally ok to answer+accept your own question